# Get id value of an element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am developing a chrome extension and I need to access the id value of an element.
The element I want to find:

```
<div class="annonce" id="45673">
```

I know how to get to class `announce` using `getElementByClassName()` but don't know how to get the value of id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `element[0].id` to get the id from a element

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("annonce");
console.log(x[0].id);
```

```html
<div class="annonce" id="45673"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following methods:

```
document.getElementById("45673");
```

or

```
document.querySelector("#45673");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.

> var x = document.getElementsByClassName("annonce")[0].id;